# Is it possible to disable the right side of the *overflow page?

Tags: support, user-interface

After hiding the nav bar which was on the left side, I would describe a stackoverflow page as having a left side and a right side. The left side is the content I am reading, takes up 66% of the page. The right side takes up ~33% with a yellowish blog box, related topics, and a chat box some kind.

I use two browser windows side by side and that right side pane eats up 1/3 of my screen with not useful information leaving me to scroll left and right to read the content :(

Is there a way to disable the entire right pane and only show the content?

I use firefox if it matters.

Comment: Constraining the width of a post to only a moderate section of the screen is generally considered to be more readable than the alternative. I remember a comment by Code Gray to this effect somewhat recently (that someone else posted as an answer) but I think the parent post was deleted, I can't find it. It would probably be pretty easy to make your own CSS to make the content span the whole page, if you really wanted to

Comment: Though, it is useful to be able to utilize the whole page *when answering*, I use something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgq7A.png to show question / answer textarea / answer preview together

Comment: If you are using an adBlocker such as uBlock Origin then you can easily create a custom rule to hide `#sidebar`

Comment: [You should use an ad blocker in general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331960) anyway.

Comment: I block ads at the DNS level, but I didn't realize you could use custom rules like that! I'm going to play with that for other purposes as well :). I was hoping for a ____overflow config setting similar to hide/collapse nav bar. It's not nearly as bad as the new reddit, but it seems like the content is being marginalized in favor of seeing how many people are chatting.

Comment: Many answers to this in a similar question on stackapps, [https://stackapps.com/questions/6652/hide-the-stack-exchange-sidebar](https://stackapps.com/questions/6652/hide-the-stack-exchange-sidebar)

Answer (score 9):

There is no built-in method to hide the "sidebar". You would have to use a user stylesheet or some other method of injecting CSS into the site. The following CSS would hide the sidebar and make the main section fill the space:

```css
#sidebar {
  display: none;
}

#mainbar {
  width: calc(100% - 24px);
}
```

Comment: is this a good use for greasemonkey?

Comment: @penchant no, stylish/stylus is more appropriate for CSS injection

Answer (score 3):

Two other methods:

- make the window **smaller**. I know this sounds crazy, but in a smaller window the content of the right column is pushed to the bottom of the page and the main column becomes wider than for a bigger window.
- disable the responsive design with the `Disable Responsiveness` link at the bottom of the page. The main column will then be displayed in full width and the right column can be reached by scrolling to the right

Comment: I'm a fan of the smaller window solution because it works without having to keep the stackoverflow cookies around, but the downside is also it makes all the other websites smaller. Disable responsiveness is I think the best answer, as long as you keep the cookies around. But caveat, you have to enable it for each *overflow site, it doesn't carry over :(

Comment: @penchant I actually have an open feature request to keep the responsiveness disabled without cookies: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316923/make-disable-responsiveness-persistent-even-when-cookies-are-cleared-not-all

Answer (score 2):

There are many good answers posted to a similar question on Stack Apps, Stack Exchange:

[Hide the Stack Exchange sidebar - Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/6652/hide-the-stack-exchange-sidebar)

Comment: I'm using one of those too :)